# Trying to parse finance.yahoo.com with Mojo and perl

Tags: perl, mojolicious, mojo

I'm failing miserably. I want to parse the following URL:

http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT?ltr=1

And capture these three sections: * All * News * Press Releases

Here's what I've come up with..

```
#!/bin/perl

use Mojo::UserAgent;
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $ua_string = "Mozila .. ";
my $url       = "http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT?p=MSFT";
my $timeout   = "5";

my $ua        = Mojo::UserAgent->new( max_redirects => 5, timeout => $timeout );
$ua->transactor->name($ua_string);

my $content = $ua->get($url)->res->dom->at('#436')->{value};

say $content;
```

Any help would be appreciated.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The way you access the DOM is not correct.

An example to parse parts of the news section would be:

```
say $ua->get($url)->res->dom->at('div#quoteNewsStream-0-Stream')->all_text;
```

Comment: Brilliant! OK. So, now I am trying to search for the A HREF inside $ua, but I can't get it right.  I changed all_text to content. I am missing how to formulate the tags but I am almost there. What am I missing?                                                                                                                             
    my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new;
    my $content = $ua->$dom->find('href#');

Comment: @BrianRehder: Since you have asked another question for your above query. I think it'd be better to accept this answer as solution and wait for answer on your new question. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work